# Connecting data points with lines in a Plotly boxplot in Python

Tags: python, plotly, boxplot, plotly-python, plotly.graph-objects

I am working on some boxplots. I found this code very helpful and I managed to replicate it for my needs:

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(1)

y0 = np.random.randn(50) - 1
y1 = np.random.randn(50) + 1

df = pd.DataFrame({'graph_name':['trace 0']*len(y0)+['trace 1']*len(y1),
                  'value': np.concatenate([y0,y1],0),
                   'color':np.random.choice([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], size=100, replace=True)}
                 )

fig = px.strip(df,
         x='graph_name',
         y='value',
         color='color',
         stripmode='overlay')

fig.add_trace(go.Box(y=df.query('graph_name == "trace 0"')['value'], name='trace 0'))
fig.add_trace(go.Box(y=df.query('graph_name == "trace 1"')['value'], name='trace 1'))

fig.update_layout(autosize=False,
                  width=600,
                  height=600,
                  legend={'traceorder':'normal'})

fig.show()
```

I am now trying to put some lines connecting the datapoints with the same colors, but I am lost. Any idea?
Something similar to this:

[image]

Comment: i think you need to define your problem a bit better. since you're randomly selecting colors for the points, the number of points with the same color between both boxplots will almost certainly be mismatched. also if you have a blue point in boxplot 1, how do you decide which corresponding blue point in boxplot 2 to connect to? i think you can only create the desired figure if you guarantee the same proportion of point colors between the data sets, and clarify the rule that you're using to connect points (the closest y value, for example)

Comment: Of course I’d have to match points… but how do you add the lines? Yes, I’d have to adjust the colors and everything, but I have no clue how to add the lines.  That is just a dummy example, you can match the colors however you prefer, again I am only interested in adding the lines for now.

Comment: okay thanks for clearing that up. if it's just a dummy example, then i can add an answer that matches points by their relative values within the data set (e.g. highest point in 1962 is matched to the highest point in 2007, and so on...)

Answer (score 0):

My first idea was to add lines to your figure by using [plotly shapes](https://plotly.com/python/shapes/#lines-positioned-relative-to-the-plot--to-the-axis-data) and specifying the start and end points in x- and y-axis coordinates. However, when you use `px.strip`, plotly implements jittering (adding randomly generated small values, say between -0.1 and 0.1, to the x-coordinates under the hood to avoid points overlapping), but as far as I know, there is no way to retrieve the exact x-coordinates of each point.

However we can get around this by using `go.Scatter` to plot all the paired points individually, adding jittering as needed to the x-values and connecting each pair of points with a line. We are basically implementing px.strip ourselves but with full control of the exact coordinates of each point.

In order to toggle colors the same way that px.strip allows you to, we need to assign all points of the same color to the same [legendgroup](https://plotly.com/python/legend/#grouped-legend-items), and also only show the legend entry the first time a color is plotted (as we don't want an legend entry for each point)

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(1)

y0 = np.random.randn(50) - 1
y1 = np.random.randn(50) + 1

## sort both sets of data so we can easily connect them with line annotations
y0.sort()
y1.sort()

df = pd.DataFrame({'graph_name':['trace 0']*len(y0)+['trace 1']*len(y1),
                  'value': np.concatenate([y0,y1],0)}
                   # 'color':np.random.choice([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], size=100, replace=True)}
                 )

fig = go.Figure()

## i will set jittering to 0.1
x0 = np.array([0]*len(y0)) + np.random.uniform(-0.1,0.1,len(y0))
x1 = np.array([1]*len(y0)) + np.random.uniform(-0.1,0.1,len(y0))

## px.colors.sequential.Plasma contains 10 distinct colors
## colors_list = np.random.choice(px.colors.qualitative.D3, size=50)
## for simplicity, we repeat it 5 times instead of selecting randomly
## this guarantees the colors appear in order in the legend
colors_list = px.colors.qualitative.D3*5
color_number = {i:color for color,i in enumerate(px.colors.qualitative.D3)} 

## keep track of whether the color is showing up for the first time as we build out the legend
colors_legend = {color:False for color in colors_list}

for x_start,x_end,y_start,y_end,color in zip(x0,x1,y0,y1,colors_list):
    ## if the color hasn't been added to the legend yet, add a legend entry
    if colors_legend[color] == False:
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Scatter(
                x=[x_start,x_end],
                y=[y_start,y_end],
                mode='lines+markers',
                marker=dict(color=color),
                line=dict(color="rgba(100,100,100,0.5)"),
                legendgroup=color_number[color],
                name=color_number[color],
                showlegend=True,
                hoverinfo='skip'
            )
        )
        colors_legend[color] = True
    ## otherwise omit the legend entry, but add it to the same legend group
    else:
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Scatter(
                x=[x_start,x_end],
                y=[y_start,y_end],
                mode='lines+markers',
                marker=dict(color=color),
                line=dict(color="rgba(100,100,100,0.5)"),
                legendgroup=color_number[color],
                showlegend=False,
                hoverinfo='skip'
            )
        )


fig.add_trace(go.Box(y=df.query('graph_name == "trace 0"')['value'], name='trace 0'))
fig.add_trace(go.Box(y=df.query('graph_name == "trace 1"')['value'], name='trace 1'))

fig.update_layout(autosize=False,
                  width=600,
                  height=600,
                  legend={'traceorder':'normal'})

fig.show()
```

[image: ![enter image description here]